# Is there any difference between using toString() method than just simply calling it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been testing some examples but I don't see any difference

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits.toString();
```

and

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
```

but it just gives me the same results..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_Conversion

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: The question is unluckily formulated. "just simply calling it" is not what you mean. I guess you mean explicitly calling toString versus relying on its implicit call.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the implicit call of toString() here.

> JavaScript calls the toString method to convert an object to a
> primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the toString method
> yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an
> object where a primitive value is expected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString